# Set of short stories, including one with a man with wings, and another about his strange family gathering

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I was thinking today about this set of short stories, but I can't remember what they were or who wrote them!

One of the stories was about a strange family, where each member has some sort of dark supernatural power, except for one boy who was 'normal'. Then another story had a man with wings, and it ends up he was a member of this strange family...

Shirley Jackson? (She's more into the horrors of real life...) Stephen King? (The stories seem a little dated for him...) Bradbury?

Anyone know!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part sounds like ***[The Homecoming](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91767)*** by Ray Bradbury which was collected in *[Dark Carnival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Carnival_%28book%29)*, *[The October Country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_October_Country)*, *[the Stories of Ray Bradbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stories_of_Ray_Bradbury)* and *[From the Dust Returned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_the_Dust_Returned)* (and is also [online](http://www.scaryforkids.com/the-homecoming-by-ray-bradbury/).)

The latter sounds like ***[Uncle Einar](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58445)*** which was also in all four of those books, so I can't narrow it down further.  All the *From the Dust Returned* stories are about the same family, [the Elliott Family](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?27957), though, so that's possibly the best match.

Comment: Uncle Einar has green wings!